# How to set dynamic class name with complex statement in ng-class?

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

That's what I have:

```
ng-class="[{loading:loadingIsOn},{ color:true}]"
```

I have problem with **color** variable. It holds string value of defined color, but I can not pass it to HTML.

By the way,

```
 ng-class="color"
```

works fine.

Comment: What's the value of loadingIsOn, what's the value of color, and what do you want the css class to be?

Comment: loadingIsOn = true, color="green", css class I want is "green"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `loadingIsOn` is true, and `color` is 'green', and you want `class="loading, green"`, then all you need is

```
ng-class="[{loading:loadingIsOn}, color]"
```